# Error not store in variable in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have command

```
store=`stat /some/path`
echo ${store}>>file.txt
```

then I echo the variable result in a file

Sometimes the file doesn't exists and I get an error as `stat: cannot stat xxxx`

However, when this error occurs, it is echoed to the stdout than stored in my variable. I would like even the error to be printed out. How can I capture the same?

Comment: Your code has multiple issues; I might suggest using http://shellcheck.net perhaps and get some tips...

Comment: Not actually to stdout, no -- it's going to *stderr* rather than to your file.

Comment: BTW, what are you accomplishing with `store=$(stat /some/path); echo ${store} >>file.txt` that you couldn't accomplish with `stat /some/path >>file.txt` (the latter with a `2>&1` if you want to redirect stderr as well)

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

You don't "capture" the error message I mean. Instead you check if the file exist *before* doing all this:

```
my_path="/some/path"
if [ -f "$my_path" ]; then
    stat "$my_path" >> file.txt
fi
```

---

It should be noted that there is a race-condition here: The file *could* be removed between the check and the `stat` command. The chances for that happening are small, but it can still happen.

Comment: Needs more quotes. And if the OP wants to redirect their stderr to a file (per the description, it sounds like that file is for human review), well, why not tell them how to do that?

Comment: Also, suggesting all-caps variable names is bad form. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html -- that namespace is reserved for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system; application-defined names should have at least one lower-case alpha character to avoid potential conflicts, as a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable.

Comment: ...re: "more quotes" -- `[ -f "$my_path" ]`, and `stat "$my_path"` -- otherwise, if it's a filename that contains spaces or globs it can be modified before being passed to `test` (in the former case) or `stat` (in the latter).

Comment: If the goal is to check, then `if ! stat "$my_path"; then : "failure case here"; fi` would be a way to retrieve the data or fail and retrieve the knowledge that it failed in an atomic operation.